# Filling Firestore document with data programmatically

Tags: json, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I already have some lists of data stored on my computer, and I want to upload them to my firestore database programmatically, without having to enter them one by one.

Have already seen some articles but none of them really worked for me.

***Note that I want to import the Initial Data that is not going to change over time, and the answer below is perfectly solving that.
I have about 100K documents to import, so programmatical upload was very crucial.

Comment: What have you tried so far? And is it for iOs, Android or web?

Comment: Seeing some articles is a good way to research but going through the Firestore [Getting Started Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart) is really best practice to get familiar with it.

Comment: Also, can you clarify the question? Are you wanting to import data directly into Firestore (which is not programmatically) or write an app that brings in your data (programmatically) so it can then be written to Firestore. If it's an import - you can only import JSON formatted data and it's a pretty specific format. For anything else, an App would be the requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **webapp NodeJS project** you can do following steps:

1) Visit https://console.firebase.google.com/project/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/settings/serviceaccounts/adminsdk and download `.json` file which authorizes your Firebase Admin SDK.

2) Upgrade your Firestore to Blaze plan (pay as you go) as free version doesn't support importing data. You can manage/limit your spending [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#manage_spending).

3) Paste the code you see in the page from step 1 to your .js file and use `admin` to import data like this:

```js
admin
  .firestore()
  .collection("NAME_OF_YOUR_ORGANIZATION")
  .add({key: 'value', key2: 'value2'})
```

If you want to edit an existing document, you can do it like this:

```js
admin
  .firestore()
  .collection("NAME_OF_YOUR_ORGANIZATION")
  .doc("UID_OF_EXISTING_DOCUMENT")
  .set({key: 'value', key2: 'value2'})
```

I suggest you to checkout the [Admin SDK documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin).

Comment: What does accessing the Admin SDK or importing data have to do with storing data in Firestore Programmatically? Perhaps this is an answer to a  different question?

Comment: @Jay He's saying he has data locally at his computer and wants to add them to Firestore programmatically, right? That sounds like an import to me. I'm not sure what you mean by "storing data in Firestore Programmatically". He said "uploading" the data which I've interpreted as "importing" the data.. Hope I didn't cause the confusion, could you please explain to me where am I confused, if so? Thx.

Comment: The question states *upload them to my firestore database **programmatically**,* meaning they want to read the data in an app they are developing, and then using the Firestore API, write that data to Firestore. e.g. the data is in a text file, they want to read the file and use that data to write JSON data to Firestore within their app.  Maybe they mean importing but programmatically usually means via an App I would think. Our app does exactly that - read a ginornmous text file, creates objects we use within the app and stores that data in Firestore.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure..I suggest we wait till he gets back to the question and elaborates more on his situation. If he says I understood the question falsely, I'll delete it. Or?

Comment: @DurkoMatko The purpose was to import the initial data, that is not going to change over time. Your answer was totally correct, although I still followed another article on medium.